# How get number of participants in zoom meeting with python

Tags: python

I recently started learning Python. I decided to take on a small project that will be useful to me. The main idea of the project is that when the number of participants in the conference zoom reaches the specified value, Zoom closes.

I tried to use different modules such as "Zoom API" and "Zoomus" but they need a subscription to Zoom, as I understood. Is there any other solution to my problem?

Comment: What did you found when researching this here on Stackoverflow?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A similar question has already been asked by someone. I found that I need a subscription to Zoom, but they didn't answer there how to do it without a subscription.